# I need to extract 1D array EMG data from MYO gesture control Armband

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, myo

I am using [this program](https://github.com/dzhu/myo-raw.git).
I opened it with Python 3.8.5 IDLE.

When I start running `myo.py`, the program works well, every 0,1 second give me back some sort of data with hexadecimal number in it. But after I make a wrong hand gesture with my hand, or move my whole arm, I get this error message:

```
"ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
 array=[356 643 848 457 250 398 309 370]."
```

The point is, I need to get 8 numbers between 200 and 1000 every 0.1 second.

Like this: `[356 643 848 457 250 398 309 370]`

But I got some hexadecimal number instead. I do not know how to convert the original data. If anyone could help I would appreciate it.

Comment: What is your question - how to convert hex to int?

Comment: No. The question is : Where can i find the code snippet that give me the error message ? Becouse there is the answer for my question. This is the reason why i copied the Git link.

Comment: "Where can i find the code snippet that give me the error message ?" how did you get the error message? first hand you ran the code right?